# Magento 2: The Logo in my Magento Theme Custom and Magento Luma parent is missing, I added the logo manually in the admin admin but still can't work

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

**This is Custom Theme:**

[image]

**My logo is missing and this is what i do, i don't know where i am missing, please help me.**

[image]

[image]

**I checked Magento Luma again and it also lost the same logo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will helps you get the logo :

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-upload-logo-magento-2.html#where-should-you-use-your-brand-logo

Comment: I followed the above way but the logo is still lost

Comment: Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148422/magento-2-sample-data-and-logo-missing-in-custom-theme and run static content deploy

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential reasons why the logo in your Magento 2 theme may be missing. Here are a few things to check:

1. Make sure that the logo image file is properly uploaded to the
   correct location in the theme's file structure.
2. Make sure that the logo image file is properly uploaded to the
   correct location in the theme's file structure.
3. Check that the logo file is referenced correctly in the Magento 2
   backend, under the **`Configuration > Design > Header section`**.
4. If you have made recent changes to your theme, ensure that the theme
   is properly set as the default and that the changes have been
   properly deployed.
5. If you are using a custom theme, check that the theme is properly
   configured and that it is not conflicting with any other themes.
6. Clear the cache and check again

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme folder **app/design/frontend/vendor/theme**

1.Create a file named **theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
        <title>Theme Title</title>
        <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
        <media>
            <preview_image>media/preview.png</preview_image>
        </media>
    </theme>
```

2.Create a file **registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/vendor/theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

3.Create **media Folder**

Add one image

- Then after check Admin Configuration

  **content->design->themes**
- Check your custom theme visible or not
- Select your custom theme

  **content->design->configuration->Default Theme->Applied Theme**
- Add logo

  **content->design->configuration->Other Settings->Header->Add logo image**

save Configuration and

run command **php bin/magento catch:flush**

[image]

Comment: Even though I followed the steps but the logo is still not showing, I took a picture of the steps I did above